# Android Emulator does not run or runs very slowly

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, virtualization, haxm

I am very enthusiastic in learning and developing android applications using the native java language. Sadly my emulator is not running at all. It ran once but it was very very very slow. I am using Eclipse and the Android ADT bundle.

If it is a hardware thing here then please see my specs below. As far as I'm concerned, these are pretty decent specs for a laptop for developing apps.

Can anyone shed some light on why the emulator is unable to run properly? I really would like to start developing apps as soon as I can.

[image: Computer specification]

Comment: 1. Try close emulator in few seconds after start. Then run emulator second time. 2. Ctrl-Alt-Del -> Task Manager -> Close all ADB.exe processes. Then start emulator. May be this hope...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try three things:

- Check whether your processor supports [`Intel HAXM`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows). This will make the
  emulator as fast as real device.
- Try [`GenyMotion`](https://www.genymotion.com/).
- Alternatively, consider developing on Linux. The Linux kernel contains a module called `kvm` that is the equivalent of the Intel HAXM driver on Windows. The emulator is blazing fast on Linux with any kind of processor.

**References:**

**1.** [**Why is the Android emulator so slow?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator).

**2.** [**Speed up your Android Emulator!**](http://jolicode.com/blog/speed-up-your-android-emulator).

**3.** [**8 Tips to Speed Up Your Android ARM Emulator**](http://delphi.org/2013/11/8-tips-to-speed-up-your-android-arm-emulator-avd/).

**4.** [**How to speed up the Android Emulator by up to 400%**](http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/speeding-up-the-android-emulator/).

Comment: Trying out the first suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, just got back online. I would like rather have it free if there is other way. So I'm not really leaning on GenyMotion, though it sounds awesome.But, yeah I tried the first suggestion and it actually ran for the first time. But, it is still very slow. Got anymore advice on to make it faster?

Comment: @oneofakind: have you tried [`BlueStacks`](http://www.bluestacks.com/) ? This is totally free and runs out-of-the-box. Its as fast as real device. Once you set it up, it shows up as a physical device in the device list.

Comment: Can you install your own APK with that? and does Andy also work?

Comment: It runs like the default emulators in Eclipse/Studio. And I don't know what you mean by "Andy" ... its working is similar to an emulator so of course it has Android. Have you tried it ?

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer for the fact that your first suggestion made it ran and giving out number of links to speed up the emulator. Thanks.

Comment: ok great, thanks .... but I've used `BlueStacks` in the past, and it works flawlessly, so make sure you try it :)

Answer (score 1):

The stock emulator is very slow. I had the same issue currently I am using **Genymotion emulator** which is way to better than the emulator that is packaged with the SDK.

here the download link:
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

Though it does not have all the features available for free